# in regard to vs. regarding

Tags: grammar

*On behalf of the President the head office is writing to you **in regard to** the development…*

The phrase in bold is supposed to be used wrongly. The right choice is "regarding". I thought that "regard to" and "regarding" are interchangeable.

Comment: "Supposed to be" by **whom**?  Either is fine with me.

Comment: By experts on English (teachers and translators) in my country. This is an excerpt from the official letter of the chancellor of our president. There are allegedly many mistakes in the letter. This one is one of them. Just as a matter of interest, here is the link on the full text https://www.info.cz/cesko/jako-na-zakladni-skole-dopis-kterym-mynar-lobboval-za-ceskou-firmu-je-plny-chyb-13014.html

Comment: "**With** regard to the development" wouldn't be incorrect too.

Comment: @bart-leby  In any language there are those who thing their rules are *correct*, and anyone who does not follow those rules is speaking *incorrectly*.  English is certainly no different.   Ironically, not all of these "experts" agree on *all* of the rules, and the differences are cause for much trivial debate.